# How get user's local time (time zones) by their phone, outlook email or city?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, exchangewebservices

I'm developing rails project, which contain searching for a users.
Each user have:

- outlook email (I am able to use Exchange API)
- Country and City

I am searching for the most fast and simple way to get user's local time or time zone.

My ideas:

1. get city coordinates via google api, and after - get timezone by voordinates
2. get time zone using other specific rest API

But this realisation of this ideas is not good cause of long request/responce delays... So it is not suitable for me.

Questions:

- Does some Exchange API exists to get user's time zone by email?
- Can you advise me better ways (JS, RoR or EWS API way) to get user's 
  time zone?

Thanks!

Comment: @spickermann Exchange Web Services API

Comment: @spickermann e.g. to check is user out of office I can use GetOofSettings API method. But does similar method for user's time zone exists?

Comment: @spickermann please upvote my question back - it already has "ews" and "exchangewebservices" tag.

Comment: What gem do you used?

Comment: @spickermann I use "exchanger" gem, but this gem supports only GetUsersAvailability API as I see... So, I'm searching for a best way - how to get user's local time (I have city and exchange email).

Comment: @spickermann I can use something like GoogleAPI to get city's coordinates and after get timezone by this coordinates... but it is too complicated I think.  That's why I'm thinking about Exchange API (outlook should know about user's timezone)

Comment: [Geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit) can do reverse geocoding  from an address and [Timezone](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone) does timecode lookup from from coordinates.

Comment: @max thanks! But requests will cause a long dalays, and I needto make more than 100k requests per 24 hour (I'm sure that geokit use Google/Yandex API which have limits for free requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My algorithm:

1. Create additional model TimezoneDictionary e.g.
2. Check for timezone in TimezoneDictionary model first.
3. if timezone value is not found in TimezoneDictionary - make a request for timezone to Google API, and save it into TimezoneDictionary:

   a) request for coordinates via [Google Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/)

   b) request for timezone via [Google TimeZone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)

And when we have timezone value ("Europe/Kyiv" e.g.) we can get local time with ActiveSupport:

```
local_time = Time.now.in_time_zone "Europe/Kyiv"
```

P.S. I created a gem [which_time](https://github.com/bmalets/which_time) for this issue (to get timzone/time by city name e.g.), so if you have the desire - use it :). I will be very thankful for pull request.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to solve this via our new API

```
curl -s 'https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/?search=Tallinn,%20Estonia&embed=city:search-results/city:item/city:timezone/tz:offsets-now' | jq '._embedded."city:search-results"[0]._embedded."city:item"._embedded."city:timezone"'
```

This would run a search on [Teleport API](http://developers.teleport.org/api/getting_started/) for city matching 'Tallinn, Estonia' and would fetch the timezone information for the result.

I used [./jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse it, the result would look like:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "tz:offsets-now": {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/timezones/iana:Europe%2FTallinn/offsets/?date=2015-09-07T11%3A41%3A00Z"
        }
      },
      "base_offset_min": 120,
      "dst_offset_min": 60,
      "end_time": "2015-10-25T01:00:00Z",
      "short_name": "EEST",
      "total_offset_min": 180,
      "transition_time": "2015-03-29T01:00:00Z"
    }
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/timezones/iana:Europe%2FTallinn/"
    },
    "tz:offsets": {
      "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/timezones/iana:Europe%2FTallinn/offsets/{?date}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "tz:offsets-now": {
      "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/timezones/iana:Europe%2FTallinn/offsets/?date=2015-09-07T11%3A41%3A00Z"
    }
  },
  "iana_name": "Europe/Tallinn"
}
```